# python ABC: forbid extra methods on derived classes?

Tags: python, abstract-class

Is there a way to prohibit derived classes from abc.ABC from adding methods if they implement an ABC?

Like so:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class Foo(ABC):
    """base class for all Foos"""

    def __init__(self, sec_type: str, metric: str) -> None:
        ...

    def some_base_method(...)

    @abstractmethod
    def m1(self, ....)

    @abstractmethod
    def m2(self, ....)
```

Legal:

```
class Bar(Foo):

    def some_base_method(... # i can override this too if i want to
    
    def m1(...

    def m2(...
```

but make any other method illegal:

```
class NoBueno(Foo): #  SHOULD RAISE
    def m1(...
    def m2(...
    def m3(....
```

Not that this is a common use case, just want to know if this is possible (sort of the opposite of `abstractmethod`

Comment: When that should raise an error? During initialization? TBH It's hard for me to think of any reason why adding more methods should not allowed.

Comment: What scenarios? This sounds like a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: Just because you *want* nothing else doesn't mean the *presence* of anything else will cause a problem.

Comment: You may be able to accomplish this for normally defined methods with a metaclass, but then it may still be possible to monkey-patch in additional methods after defining the class.  It would be overly difficult to prevent any possible means of doing this, and it will only frustrate the developers trying to use it.

Comment: @dskrypa I would suggest `__init_subclass__` over a metaclass, but the rest of your comment holds.

Comment: Fair point, it would be possible that way too.

Comment: @chepner whether this should be done is a different question than whether it could. I just want to know if this is possible using the standard language.

Comment: @BartoszStasiak in terms of when, I was assuming at the same time the error is raised if you don't override an `abstractmethod`.

Comment: There are multiple approaches that could work for this, but there are also multiple ways to defeat those approaches.  What if a subclass `class Baz(Foo, ABC):` is defined with additional `@abstractmethod`s?  Should a concrete implementation of that class be restricted to only the abstract methods defined in `Foo`?  What if additional abstract methods are monkey-patched into `Foo`?  Why bother with this restriction if there are so many ways to potentially (relatively easily) defeat it?  The ROI is not apparent.